# How to process next request without waiting response for previous request

Tags: php

i have a backend system using PHP to handle transaction.
in this case, there is three environment involved.
A = client, B = my system, C = payment gateway
the scenario is :

1. client (A) send request over HTTP post request,then
2. my system (B) receive that request and then
3. send request to payment gateway (C) using cUrl.

what happen now is : 
every request from client proceed by my system partially, which mean next process will be process when previous request to C has response.

what i want is :
even the prevoius request not yet responded by C, my system can receive next request from A and send another request to C.

Comment: Most web servers can run multiple instances of a PHP script concurrently. What's causing yours to serialize them?

Comment: You could, map the request with client id and forward the parallel request from B->C , without waiting for the response from C. Once "C" will respond, map the response data with client id.

Comment: When you are using a session, make sure your session is not write enabled during the "longy" call - it will block all further active scripts